# Understanding and Optimizing Generational Garbage Collection in Haskell

Tags: haskell, garbage-collection, ghc

When a program initializes, the mutator allocates memory space for new small objects in the nursery. The nursery serves as a buffer to maintain recently created objects. If these objects remain alive during the garbage collection cycle, they may undergo aging and be promoted to Generation 0 for small objects or Generation 1 for large objects. So, the nursery, Gen 0, and Gen 1 are pipelining with each other and interacting accordingly. I want to explain my understanding as follow:

1. **Nursery:**

   - Newly allocated objects start in the nursery, designed for short-lived objects.
2. **Garbage Collection Cycle:**

   - The garbage collector examines nursery objects during a cycle.
   - Surviving objects in the nursery may age within the same generation (e.g., Gen 0).
3. **Generational Promotion:**

   - Objects surviving multiple cycles may be promoted to the next older generation (e.g., from Gen 0 to Gen 1).
4. **Interaction and Pipeline:**

   - Objects move through a pipeline-like structure: nursery to Gen 0, and potentially to Gen 1.
   - The nursery buffers short-lived objects, Gen 0 represents the initial stage for object promotion, and Gen 1 (and further generations) accommodates objects with longer lifetimes.

Is my understanding correct?

I expect the some helpful explanations.

Comment: I means GHC current version. Thanks.

Comment: @JörgWMittag pretty much everybody uses GHC. The only exception are obscure educational usages which have stuck with Hugs though it has been obsolete for a long while. Haskell and GHC aren't the same thing, yet for questions about how Haskell does XYZ it's generally safe to assume what's meant is how GHC does it.

Comment: I see you are asking a lot of questions about ghc's implementation details. Probably you can get better responses in other forums, since stackoverflow is more focused on specific code. I'd suggest https://discourse.haskell.org/ in which these kind of questions frequently debated